# Excel automation. How to copy more than one cell?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, excel, com, automation

**For instance:**

```
 //omitted

vector<_bstr_t> cellData;

Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = application->ActiveSheet;

Excel::RangePtr pRange = application->Cells;

_bstr_t cellValue = pRange->Item[1][1]; //single cell

cellData.push_back(cellValue);

 //omitted
```

**Without:**

- MFC
- ATL

**Question:**

- How to copy, **multiple** cells, for instance A1:B1, into the vector?
- Is there a more **appropriate** method, instead of **Item**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done any Excel automation using C++, but if it works similarly as VBA macros, the WorkSheet class should have a Range property that returns a range of cells in the sheet. You can specify what range you want either by giving two cells id, or a string representing the range.

Code in pseudo VBA:

```
Dim range As Range
Set range = ActiveSheet.Range("B12:D34")
Set range = ActiveSheet.Range("B12", "D34")
Set range = ActiveSheet.Range("B12", ActivSheet.Range("D34"))
...
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range(VS.80).aspx) for more information about the Range class.